# disable a select in a loop on condition JS

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a `<tr v-for="(share, index) in sharesList" :key="index">` through which I am creating a table of `shares`.

whereas I want to disable it, with a few conditions, such as when the current user which is logged in don't have full rights all select's should be to that user.

I have a current user as `junaid@evercam.io` and a share as

```
{ "id": 68502, "fullname": "Junaid Farooq", "user_id": "junaid@evercam.io", "email": "affan@evercam.io", "sharer_name": "Junaid Farooq", "sharer_email": "junaid@evercam.io", "permission": "minimal+share", "camera_id": "doyle-bapxc" }
```

Now if my permissions are not FULL I want to disable each select for me.

this is how selects are manipulated

```
  <v-select
    v-model="share.permission"
    :items="rights"
    class="caption pt-0 mt-0"
    hide-details
    return-object
    :disabled="CanChangeRights(share, loggedInUser)"
    @change="changeRights($event, share.id, share.email, 'shares')"
  >
    <template v-slot:item="data">
      <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title class="caption" v-text="data.item.text" />
      </v-list-item-content>
    </template>
      </v-select>
```

I have added a method to `:disable` such as `CanChangeRights(share, loggedInUser)`

in which I am doing this

```
  if (share.email == loggedInUser && share.permission != "full") {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
```

which works all fine but only for my share select. not all,

I want to check if `(share.email == loggedInUser && share.permission != "full")` this is true then disable every select in in above `v-for`.

how is that possible? every help would be thankful

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "disable every select". Are there more selects for each row (share) ? Because it doesn't make sense to disable all selects (each for different share) based on permissions to single share...